# What's the issue in assigning a comma separated string value to a variable in following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-ui

Following is the static code example :

```
new Taggle('example2', {
    tags: ['These', 'are', 'prefilled', 'tags']
});
```

The above code is working fine. But when I tried to assign a variable containing a string of comma separated values I'm not able to execute the code properly.

Following is the code I tried :

var mail_list = $('#contact_us_email_list').val();
//Value contained in a variable mail_list is **abc@gmail.com,lmn.pqr@gmail.com, jumbo@yahoo.co.in**

```
new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {
    tags: mail_list
});
```

Can someone please tell me what mistake I'm making while passing the variable value as a parameter for **tags**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `mail-list.split(',')`.

Comment: tags accepts an array, if mail_list is a string then use above `mail-list.split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass them in an array:

```
var mail_list = ['abc@gmail.com','lmn.pqr@gmail.com', 'jumbo@yahoo.co.in'];
new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {
    tags: mail_list
});
```

Or, you can split the string so it would be an array, then use as usual.

```
var mail_list = $('#contact_us_email_list').val();
new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {
        tags: mail_list.split(',')
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://sean.is/poppin/tags) explains you can use `add`. So why not just add the string to the new taggle ensuring that you convert it to an array first with `split`.

```
var taggle = new Taggle('example2');
var arr = $('#contact_us_email_list').val().split(',');
taggle.add(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assigning a String to `tags`, but it expects an array. Just split your value by `,`.

Just use it like bellow

```
new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {
    tags: mail_list.split(',')
});
```